# How to compile an iOS project from command line

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, fastlane, fastlane-gym

I want to *assemble/compile* a workspace with cocoapods on it but without:

- Archiving.
- Need to setup credentials or pem files.

Something like:
`xcodebuild assemble`

I want to know if the code compiles but not generate an archive or a deployed artifact.

I tried [fastlane/gym](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/gym/) but it tries to create an archive.

Comment: xcodebuild <path to project> -scheme <scheme name> build

Comment: @Marcel when I run that I got errors, but from xcode it compiles and run on the emulator `Exiting early, found no Swift version in executables.`

Comment: Looks like you don't have the language version set in the build settings, try opening the project in xcode and check the target's build settings. Are you by any chance using cocoapods?

Comment: Sorry, missed that in the question, you are using cocoapods. Try the workaround you can find on the following page: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5521

Comment: @Marcel the info was not in the question, I edited it. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Using xcodebuild

You can compile a project with the following command:

```
xcodebuild <path to project> -scheme <scheme name> build
```

Because you are using cocoapods, you should compile using the workspace, instead of the project, like this:

```
xcodebuild -workspace <path to workspace file> -scheme <scheme name> build
```

If the swift version is not set in the cocoapods target there is a workaround by adding the following to your Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
   end
  end
end
```

## Using fastlane

Another way is using `build_app` from [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/), like:

```
build_app(scheme: 'YourScheme',
          workspace: 'YourProject.xcworkspace',
          skip_archive: true,
          skip_package_ipa: true,
          include_bitcode: false)
```

I prefer this way, since it makes it simpler and uses [xcpretty](https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty) that will print the output nicer than `xcodebuild`.